# How to use ORDER BY with roman numbers and DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-order-by

I have this code:

```
 WITH CTE_MATRICULA AS
    (
        SELECT CODIGO, CICLO, NOTA, fecha
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODIGO, CICLO ORDER BY fecha DESC) AS RN
        FROM CI_MATRICULA
        WHERE codigo ='021502618' and idioma='003' and nota>=15
    )
    SELECT CODIGO, CICLO, NOTA, CONVERT (char(8),fecha, 3) as FECHA_FORMATEADA
    INTO #TEMP_MATRICULA
    FROM CTE_MATRICULA
    WHERE RN = 1

    SELECT CODIGO, CICLO, NOTA, FECHA_FORMATEADA
    FROM #TEMP_MATRICULA
    order by FECHA_FORMATEADA desc
```

with this code can order almost all, but when shows the result can't order the cicle "IX", maybe i make some uncorrect.

The output is:

> 021502618 I   19  08/03/16
>
> 021502618 II  19  06/04/16
>
> 021502618 III 17  03/05/16
>
> 021502618 IV  17  05/07/16
>
> 021502618 IX  16  04/07/17
>
> 021502618 V   18  02/09/16
>
> 021502618 VI  16  04/11/16
>
> 021502618 VII 16  06/12/16
>
> 021502618 VIII    17  04/03/17
>
> 021502618 X   16  02/10/17
>
> 021502618 XI  16  03/01/18
>
> 021502618 XII 16  05/03/18
>
> 021502618 XIII    18  05/04/18
>
> 021502618 XIV 18  04/05/18
>
> 021502618 XIX 15  07/01/19
>
> 021502618 XV  15  05/07/18
>
> 021502618 XVI 15  04/09/18
>
> 021502618 XVII    17  05/11/18
>
> 021502618 XVIII   16  04/12/18
>
> 021502618 XX  16  05/04/19
>
> 021502618 XXI 15  05/08/19

how can modify this code for run the correct order by cicle?
or necessarily i need another way to order this?

Comment: In English por favor. Or post/move it to https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: This is because roman numerals are characters. They are sorting by the rules of how characters sort. You have the same problem if you sort by FECHA_FORMATEADA because you took your date and turned into characters. Roman numerals are tough to say the least for sorting. You will need a function to turn the roman numeral into arabic numbers (0 - 9).

Comment: Here is one way you can convert roman numerals to arabic numbers (aka integers). https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/roman-numerals-to-integers-and-vice-versa-in-sql

Answer (score -1):

Effectively Sean Lange. the error is on the type of variable. i've soluted with this:

```
WITH CTE_MATRICULA AS
(
SELECT CODIGO, (case
        WHEN CICLO= 'I' then CAST('1' AS INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'II' then CAST('2' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'III' then CAST('3' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'IV' then CAST('4' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'V' then CAST('5' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'VI' then CAST('6' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'VII' then CAST('7' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'VIII' then CAST('8' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'IX' then CAST('9' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'X' then CAST('10' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XI' then CAST('11' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XII' then CAST('12' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XIII' then CAST('13' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XIV' then CAST('14' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XV' then CAST('15' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XVI' then CAST('16' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XVII' then CAST('17' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XVIII' then CAST('18' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XIX' then CAST('19' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XX' then CAST('20' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XXI' then CAST('21' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XXII' then CAST('22' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XXIII' then CAST('23' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XXIV' then CAST('24' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XXV' then CAST('25' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XXVI' then CAST('26' as INTEGER)
        END) AS CICLO, NOTA, fecha
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODIGO, CICLO ORDER BY fecha DESC) AS RN
    FROM CI_MATRICULA
  WHERE codigo =@codigo and idioma=@idioma and nota>=15
)
SELECT CODIGO, CICLO, NOTA, CONVERT (char(8),fecha, 3) as FECHA_FORMATEADA
INTO #TEMP_MATRICULA
FROM CTE_MATRICULA
WHERE RN = 1

SELECT CODIGO, CICLO, NOTA, FECHA_FORMATEADA
FROM #TEMP_MATRICULA
order by CICLO
```

THANKS A LOT

Comment: there are several problems with this approach.
it works only if there is at most 26 roman numbers in your table.
and, if you want to re-use your query, you should write a function instead of this giant CASE expression.